# Jquery returns undefined in my code

Tags: jquery

I want to return the following response from my jquery code.

```
function count_waiting(){   
    $.ajax({                                                    
      url: 'index.php/event/count_waiting/2',                           
      type: "post", 
      success: function(response) {         
       return response;     
      } 
    });

}
```

By doing this the return is undifned

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(count_waiting());
});
```

any idea whats wrong with my code

Comment: What is `event_id` in the scope of the `ready` method? I don't think it exists. You must define it.

Comment: your code is working asynchronously - this is the reason.

Comment: check whether you're getting response.

Comment: Try alerting 'response' within the success callback. Also, I suggest using safari/chrome and debugging Ajax calls with the built in Inspector tools

Comment: it returns the result when I tried the ALERT.. inside the ajax

Comment: i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call  but still undefined

Comment: this is the answer set async: false.... u_mulder is right

Answer (score 0):

an [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request is async . when you call you count_waiting function, probably your request has not been processed and the result is not yet ready.

When the success callback is fired, your data is ready; call a function(with the result as argument) inside of it or use your data directly here.

Comment: the explanation is correct, but what is the solution? Also, guessing is not welcome here. Also, why link to the italian wikipedia?

Comment: sorry for IT link, just a typo.

Comment: oh no! async: false is the answer